# Condition outside {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} in C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

For a project I am currently checking a string using an index. I know that I can use that kind of condition:

```
if (index >= '0' && index <= '9')
```

But how can I do to put a condition saying "If my index IS NOT included between 0 and 9, do this" ?
Like, if at any time str[index] != 0 or 1 or ... or 9, I exit.

How can I do that condition in C please?

Comment: Have you come across `else`?

Comment: @kaylum you mean using an if/else forest? Like if different 0, else if different 1, etc? It's not clean :(

Comment: 'less than '0' or greater than '9'

Comment: ..or just not the whole of your existing condition.

Comment: Suggest you go through a basic C book or tutorial. This will be covered in the very first few lessons.

Comment: ..or read your exiting conditino into a temp boolean called .'in0to9'' and then != that.

Comment: `if (index >= 0 && index <= 9) { // do this} else { // do that}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways:

1. `if (!(str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= '9'))`
2. `if (str[index] < '0' || str[index] > '9')`
3. `#include <ctype.h>` and use `if (!isdigit(str[index]))`
4. Use an `else`

I personally prefer the third one.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite simple.Just write `if (! (index >= '0' && index <= '9')) { /* */ }`

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have made a condition and you want a condition opposite to yours then simply you can use else with that

```
if (index >= '0' && index <= '9'){
//do something
{
else
{
exit(0);
}
```

or if you don't want to do that and simply wants to reverse the result of the condition then put a not (!) in front of the condition

```
if (!(index >= '0' && index <= '9')){
exit(0);
}
```

for more information [see here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/2016_03_01_archive.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed the second one!